# A problem with functions.php file on my WordPress site

Tags: themes

When I add `functions.php` file to my WordPress website, my website just stops working.

It doesn't matter if I have or have not code there, whenever the `functions.php` file is present, the site stops working. I tried to check if there is any typo or parser error, but I can't find nothing nor the debugger doesn't report anything. This happens also when I follow tutorial in a book.

Comment: Switch to a default theme that ships with WP and turn off all plugins. Try it there, report back (in an edit to the question) if the problem persists.

Comment: Impossible to answer without [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). And yes, there *must* be some error in the logs.

Comment: Wellcome aboard @Coder. We need coders like you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your debug log to know actual problem on your site.

**Enable Debug** log from your site though below steps:

1. Open `wp-config.php` from your WordPress setup.
2. Add below lines

   define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

   define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

   define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );

And just refresh the page.

Now you can see the error message's and warnings behind your problem.

For more information @see https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

So, You know the actual reason of why **functions.php** not working on your site.

Comment: Very solid answer @maheshwaghmare

Answer (score -2):

> I'm quite new to WordPress and I have a problem. I don't know how many of you has the same problem, but always when I add functions.php file to my WordPress website, my website just stops working.

You are maybe overwriting the existing `function.php` file when you add `functions.php` to your site.

You should just edit your `functions.php` file that exists insite your theme.

Many new Wordpress coders did that and this is OK, while you are the novice. Wellcome aboard to WordPress and to this website.

Comment: @Coder It's difficult to know what's the reason behind this.

Comment: @maheshwaghmare, yes bro, the part of the question was he is the very new in WordPress, and just followed some tutorial, and chances are he overwrote the file.